# How can I get Webstorm to recognize my LESS file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, less, webstorm

Webstorm 8.03
AngularJS
RequireJS
LESS
etc.

In my require definitions, I have less files that Webstorm thinks aren't there:

`define([
     'blahblah',
     'less!../../styles/myStyle'
]`

If i refactor it to the following it works fine:

`'../../styles/myStyle.less'`

The problem is our code style dictates to use the 'less!' plugin instead of the file extension. Is there a way to get Webstorm to find the files properly using the first code style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Please follow [WEB-1167](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1167) for more updates on this webstorm issue.